# Money supply question

Tags: money-supply

If relative interest rates in US dollars compared to other countries currencies go up assuming everything else stays the same does this automatically decrease the money supply? At first you would think the answer is obviously yes but confidence in the economy as well as the cost of borrowing affect the money supply. Are there any actual studies that measure the money supply including velocity?

Velocity I assume is an economic term people understand maybe it's not. If it isn't already an economic term considerate how often a dollar is spent through an economy confidence is a Big driver. If you increase interest rates trying to reduce the money supply and inflation, you are saying the economy is strong enough that inflation is a greater risk. In a way you increase the confidence of economic participants. These two forces velocity and the cost of money seem like they could work in opposite directions. Do you understand my question?